# Haskell data type error

Tags: haskell, types

I have this function:

```
data Memory = Memory
    {visited::[Point]
    ,dfsstack::[Point]
    ,currentPoz::Point
    }deriving(Eq)
perceiveAndAct :: SVal -> [Cardinal] -> a -> (Action, a)
perceiveAndAct s cs m
  | elem W cs == True && elem N cs == True && elem E cs == True && elem S cs == False = (Just S, Memory (visited m) (dfsstack m) (currentPoz m))
```

putting m instead of  `Memory (visited m) (dfsstack m) (currentPoz m)` works fine, else it gives me that:

```
Couldn't match expected type `(a, b)'
           against inferred type `Memory -> Point'
    In the first argument of `fst', namely `currentPoz'
    In the first argument of `($)', namely `fst currentPoz'
    In the expression: fst currentPoz $ currentPoz m
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Where is the `fst currentPoz $ currentPoz m` the error message is referring to?

Comment: Btw, everywhere you have `blah == True`, you can simplify that to just `blah` (e.g. simplify `elem W cs == True` to `elem W cs`). Similarly, you can simplify `elem S cs == False` to `notElem S cs`.

Answer (score 5):

The type you gave `perceiveAndAct` is very polymorphic. Compare:

```
id :: a -> a
id m = m -- the only correct implementation
id m = Memory (visited m) (dfsstack m) (currentPoz m) -- type error
-- only works for Memory, not all possible a

idMemory :: Memory -> Memory
id m = m -- this is fine
id m = Memory (visited m) (dfsstack m) (currentPoz m) -- also correct
```

However, I'm a little confused, since the type error you pasted does not match the type error I get when I make the change you claimed you made. Perhaps you'd better paste the exact code you use that gives an error together with the exact error you got, rather than the correct code and the error for some invisible code we can't see.

Answer (score -1):

`visited`, `dfsstack`, and `currentPoz` are functions, and they don't construct lists.

You want to write `Memory [m] [m] m`, instead.

`visited`, `dfsstack`, and `currentPoz` are functions which, *given* `someData :: Memory`, can extract each of these elements.

You'll also need to change the type of `perceiveAndAct`'s argument "m" from `:: a` to `:: Point`